# AWS Cloudwatch disk metrics showing values as zero

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

The Cloudwatch disk metrics values of EC2 instance that is causing problems, there are no data. I am using C4.xlarge instance and the root device type is EBS. In Cloudwatch following metrics are shown as zero,

- Disk Reads(Bytes)
- Disk Read Operations
- Disk Writes(Bytes)
- Disk Write Operations

The Minimum,Maximum,Average and Sum of the above items are zero.

Network and CPU monitors return data fine.

Any idea why ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

Those metrics are not for EBS volumes, they are for [instance store volumes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html), which the C4 class doesn't have.

For EBS volumes, see the metrics for the individual volumes.